# SSRS 2012 Recursive Hierarchy over several columns

Tags: reporting-services, recursion, report, hierarchy

I am currently struggling with a report I'm creating in SSRS 2012. I have a dataset with a 4 level hierarchy and want to create a recursive hierarchy. Everywhere I look I find ways to create this hierarchy in one column and use padding to differenciate between different levels. However, my report is to be exported to Excel and have the opportunity to filter by the values in the columns. This means I need to divide each level in the hierarchy into different columns.

I am working with locations, so I have one Location_ID, and a Parent_Location_ID

In the end I want the hierarchy in the report to look something like below.

```
xxxx
  xxxx
    xxxx
      xxxx
      xxxx
      xxxx
    xxxx
      xxxx
  xxxx
    xxxx
      xxxx
      xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were to design the report, I would decide on the maximum number of level to be handled in the hierarchy, let's say 10.

Then I would have a query return the maximum encountered, and use the results of that query to hide any unused columns.

My core data query would then have a fixed set of columns:

```
Level1  Level2 Level3 .... Level10 MyDataField1 MyDataField2
```

And I'd generate these in the SQL query. It would be messy, repetitive SQL (not DRY.) But it would be easy to handle on the SSRS and export side.

Comment: Thank you for the respons. I want to use the datasets I already have and avoid messy SQL. I ended up creating a recursive hierarchy in one column which I then hid and displayed the values in the hierarchy in columns made visible or not by checking for the level of the location. This doesn't give me the full funcionality that I want since I can't merge columns vertically, but for now it is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

[This tech net reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255243.aspx) may be useful for anyone else trying to solve recursive relationship in SSRS over a single column. In my case I started to look at multiple columns but a single column ended up working well.

**To create a recursive hierarchy group:**

1. In Design view, add a table, and drag the dataset fields to display. Typically, the field that you want to show as a hierarchy is in the first column.
2. Right-click anywhere in the table to select it. The Grouping pane displays the details group for the selected table. In the Row Groups pane, right-click Details, and then click Edit Group. The Group Properties dialog box opens.
3. In Group expressions, click Add. A new row appears in the grid.
4. In the Group on list, type or select the field to group.
5. Click Advanced.
6. In the Recursive Parent list, enter or select the field to group on.
7. Click OK.
8. Run the report.

To add an indent to show the hierarchy levels. You can add padding left to the text box by using:

```
=CStr(2 + (Level()*10)) + "pt"
```